Jaspersoft Studio - setting up JSON / Java DataAdapter & rendering preview
I'm currently struggling a lot with making a report using Jaspersoft Studio 6.3, because the preview function doesn't work. The report is to be used in a java project, so all text field expressions had this format:
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{c}.getManufacturer()]]></textFieldExpression>

First I tried adding Collection of JavaBeans Data Adapter, providing a .jar file that has the appropriate class, but it's not found:

Then I tried providing a JSON-datasource, which seems to be read and mapped correctly in the Dataset and Query Dialog:

It put field definitions in the file, which I referenced like this:
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{originalUnitNo}]]></textFieldExpression>

Now when the preview finally renders, all those text field expressions just show "null".
What did I do wrong there?
